# Where conditions. != in two fields

Tags: sql, sybase, where-clause

This query gives me exactly what i want, BUT it's not nice ;)

```
select *
from sel, (
    select * from sel where ttype = 15) as dl15
where ttype = 16
and sel.code = dl15.code
and convert(varchar,dl15.vdate,0)+convert(varchar, dl15.vtime,0) !=
    convert(varchar,sel.vdate,0)+convert(varchar, sel.vtime,0)
```

maybe someone can help me to convert this conditions `convert(varchar,dl15.vdate,0)+convert(varchar, dl15.vtime,0) != convert(varchar,sel.vdate,0)+convert(varchar, sel.vtime,0)` to more correct form

subquery result:

```
id          code    vdate               vtime
2000983484  3374347 Feb  1 2020 12:00AM Dec 30 1899  7:05PM
```

result without last conditions

```
id          code    vdate               vtime
2000983885  3374347 Feb  6 2020 12:00AM Dec 30 1899  8:00AM
2000983485  3374347 Feb  1 2020 12:00AM Dec 30 1899  7:43PM
2000952328  3374347 Feb  1 2020 12:00AM Dec 30 1899  7:05PM
```

needed result

```
id          code    vdate               vtime
2000983885  3374347 Feb  6 2020 12:00AM Dec 30 1899  8:00AM
2000983485  3374347 Feb  1 2020 12:00AM Dec 30 1899  7:43PM
```

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: post updated...

Comment: If it's working, then there is no error. Also code is quite readable. What you mean by `more correct form`?

Comment: I hope to find some form without joining 2 fields for compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `vdate/vtime` are of type `datetime` and include (milli/micro)seconds that are to be ignored (hence the `convert(...,0)`)
- all columns are wanted from both tables

One query idea:

```
select s15.*,s16.*
from   sel s15
join   sel s16
on     s15.code  = s16.code
and    s15.ttype = 15
and    s16.ttype = 16
where (   convert(varchar,s15.vdate,0) != convert(varchar,s16.vdate,0)
       or convert(varchar,s15.vtime,0) != convert(varchar,s16.vtime,0)
      )
```

A variation on the `where` clause since `smalldatetime` is accurate to the minute (ie, `smalldatetime` has no seconds):

```
where (   convert(smalldatetime,s15.vdate) != convert(smalldatetime,s16.vdate)
       or convert(smalldatetime,s15.vtime) != convert(smalldatetime,s16.vtime)
      )
```

And if `vdate/vtime` are of type `smalldatetime` then there should be no need to call `convert()`:

```
where (   s15.vdate != s16.vdate
       or s15.vtime != s16.vtime
      )
```

Comment: Thank you for datetime  - this is a decides,
and about join I will try it, thanks one else

Answer (score 0):

This is better:

```
select *
from sel
join (select * from sel where ttype = 15) as dl15
on sel.code = dl15.code
and  convert(varchar,dl15.vdate,0)+convert(varchar, dl15.vtime,0) !=
     convert(varchar,sel.vdate,0)+convert(varchar, sel.vtime,0)
where ttype = 16 -- here add an table alias sel or dl15
```

Comment: as I know 'join on' and conditions in 'where' the same, maybe I wrong, but in any case question be a bit difference.

Comment: Well, I think that if anything this is more readable (you asked for some nice code hehe). Also please can you show us the columns ´code´ from both tables ? Thanks!

Comment: sorry it's mu mistake, when format data example I have mistake ttype = code.

Comment: Id is the corect column? O I see. Ok.

Comment: Plesae can you tell me what result do you get when you do this query: `select convert(varchar,sel.vdate,0) , convert(varchar, sel.vtime,0) from sel;¨two examples only please thanks!

Comment: hi, 1st & 2nd in example.

Comment: Hi @Sfagnum no no, that is not what I ask. `select convert(varchar,sel.vdate,0) , convert(varchar, sel.vtime,0) from sel;` Run this and give me two rows of results.